# What is the physics behind a hard phone cover and a soft phone cover?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, momentum, everyday-life, collision

Does hard plastic distribute forces throughout a device, similar to how the shell of an egg works, much better than a soft cover does? This is the common argument I hear for the hard cover.

How different is it from a soft plastic case? For soft plastic, I have the understanding that it increases time of impact, hence leading to a smaller force on the device when dropped.

Answer (score -2):

One has a lower Young's modulus than the other. That's it.

Comment: Physics applies perfectly to macroscopic world. You insult Newton by saying otherwise. However, things do get tricky in the quantum world.

Comment: "All of the macroscale properties are outside the realm of physics, physics is mostly about vague theories about things too small to see"  That's just blatantly untrue.  Although _some_ branches of modern physics focus on that, there are _plenty_ of branches of physics that focus on other aspects of it.  Also "One has a lower Young's modulus than the other. That's it." is not true either.  There are many other factors that decide the way a case protects your phone.  That's vastly oversimplifying the problem.

Comment: Looking at your other answers, you seem to have a decent knowledge of physics (though your answers received a few downvotes due to insufficient support or elaboration). As such, I’m perplexed as to how this can be a genuine answer.